# StructureMap and open generic types

Tags: c#, structuremap

I cant get the StructureMap `IAssemblyScanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing` method to pickup my implementations.

Specifically, given following definition (lifted from Mass Transit),

```
public class Consumes<TMessage> where TMessage : class
{
    public Consumes();

    public static Consumes<TMessage>.Selected Null { get; }

    public interface All : IConsumer
    {
        void Consume(TMessage message);
    }
  }
```

I have multiple implementations of `Consumes<TMessage>.All` declared as follows,

```
class TrendReportRequestConsumer : Consumes<TrendReportRequest>.All
{ ...

class CountReportRequestConsumer : Consumes<CountReportRequest>.All
{ ...
```

If I setup structuremap using,

```
Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();                
            scan.IncludeNamespaceContainingType<TrendReportRequestConsumer>();
            scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(Consumes<>.All));
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
```

It doesnt work BUT if I add the implementations explicitly

```
        For<Consumes<TrendReportRequest>.All>().Use<TrendReportRequestConsumer>();
        For<Consumes<CountReportRequest>.All>().Use<CountReportRequestConsumer>();
```

It works.

Is my understanding of an open generic type faulty ??? ie. `Consumes<TMessage>.All` is an interface definition in a generic class so does this make it an open generic type?